# Is quarantine threats absolutely necessary? Every time I do, all my Chrome tabs crash

Tags: malware, chrome, synchronization, quarantine

I have been talking backwards and forwards with a MalwareByte support, because every time I run 'quarantine threats' all my Chrome tabs crash. This guy keeps asking me to switch Google sync off, and then resetting it, except that there is no reset sync button anywhere. Most of all, he won't answer my question: do I really need to quarantine threats?

Comment: It is really up to the product and what *exactly* it does.

Comment: There's no "reset" button, but that's not what is meant. It means to turn off then on again.